# replace a column using regex in ms access 2010

Tags: regex, ms-access, replace, ms-access-2010

There's a table named sample including only one column, body (type: text) in ms access 2010:

```
<name>John</name><age>12</age>
```

I'd like to delete every string inside the brackets. See this:

```
John12
```

I added Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5 library and create this module:

```
Function Replace_Regex(str1, patrn, replStr)
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = patrn
regEx.IgnoreCase = True

Replace_Regex = regEx.Replace(str1, replStr)
End Function
```

And then, I run this query:
    update sample
    set body = Replace_Regex(body, "<[^>]+?", "")

But the result is:

```
 ame>John</name><age>12</age>
```

So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the function:

```
regEx.Global = True
```

Then use `"<[^>]*>"` as the pattern.

Here's what I get in the Immediate window:

```
body = "<name>John</name><age>12</age>"
? Replace_Regex(body, "<[^>]*>", "")
John12
```