# Column comparison by ignoring other characters

Tags: ms-access-2007

How to compare two columns in MS Access by ignoring other characters like .',"

For example follwing two column data should tally

```
Col1         Col2

"adA.'kd,"  adA.kd
```

Appreciate your response

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend using Regex then you might use the character class `\W` (equivalent to `[^\w]`) in the replace, meaning any non-word character. This excludes digits and the underscore though. If you want to replace these as well then consider `[^A-Za-z]`; that is, anything that is not a letter.

Access Functions include `Replace` but it is not very useful for this as it doesn't allow us to specify a group of characters to replace. If you are using an Access Query to perform the comparison then you might create a VBA function that you can use in the query, similar to the following.

```
Function GetAlpha(strInput As String) As String
    'Returns a string containing only the letters from the input
    Dim strCheck As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLen As Integer
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim ch As String

    strCheck = strInput   'remember the original input
    strInput = LCase(strInput)    'ignore case temporarily
    iLen = Len(strInput)
    For i = 1 To iLen
        ch = Mid(strInput, i, 1)
        If ch >= "a" And ch <= "z" Then
            'if a letter, build a string using the original letter from the input
            strOutput = strOutput & Mid(strCheck, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    GetAlpha = strOutput
End Function
```

In an Access query you would create an expression such as

```
IIF(GetAlpha([Field1])=GetAlpha([Field2]),"Same","Different")
```

Access ignores case though. If you wan't to include case-sensitivity then you could use `StrComp()` as well, or modify my function to include two (string) arguments and return a Boolean value. Rather than modify the function though, you could use the following:

```
Function CompareAlpha(strInput1 As String, strInput2 As String) As Boolean
    'case-insensitive comparison of the letters of two strings
    CompareAlpha = (StrComp(GetAlpha(strInput1), GetAlpha(strInput2), _
        vbBinaryCompare) = 0)
End Function
```

The following function does exactly the same as GetAlpha() above but is perhaps slightly neater:

```
Function GetAlpha(strInput As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLen As Integer
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim ch As String

    iLen = Len(strInput)
    For i = 1 To iLen
        ch = LCase(Mid(strInput, i, 1))
        If ch >= "a" And ch <= "z" Then
            strOutput = strOutput & Mid(strInput, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    GetAlpha = strOutput
End Function
```

Edited: The following similar function checks to see if a string contains only letters. (I've included it in case it is of use to anyone else.)

```
Function CheckAlpha(strInput As String) As Boolean
    Dim strCheck As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLen As Integer
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim ch As String

    strCheck = strInput    'store the original input to compare later
    strInput = LCase(strInput)    'temporarily ignore case
    iLen = Len(strInput)
    For i = 1 To iLen
        ch = Mid(strInput, i, 1)
        If ch >= "a" And ch <= "z" Then
            'construct a string of only the letters from the original input
            strOutput = strOutput & Mid(strCheck, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    'is the letters-only version the same as the original input?
    CheckAlpha = (strCheck = strOutput)
    'use StrComp() for case-sensitivity. That is, we could use StrComp() to 
    'check if all letters were upper, or lower, case.
End Function
```

**Added** In response to a comment, if the data may contain NULL values then the following revision will return an empty string "" rather than a `Type Mismatch` error. The alternative is to exclude NULLs before calling GetAlpha().

```
Function GetAlpha(varInput As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLen As Integer
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim ch As String

    If IsNull(varInput) Then
        GetAlpha = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    iLen = Len(varInput)
    For i = 1 To iLen
        ch = LCase(Mid(varInput, i, 1))
        If ch >= "a" And ch <= "z" Then
            strOutput = strOutput & Mid(varInput, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    GetAlpha = strOutput
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have just a few characters to ignore, you can try [replacing](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php) them with empty strings. A better way would be to do a regex replacement, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188796/replace-a-column-using-regex-in-ms-access-2010), where your regex pattern (the `patrn` variable in your case would be the regex "[.,'\"]" to ignore period, comma, single quote, and double quote (but I'm not sure how escapes work in MS Access), and the `replStr` would just be "", the empty string)

Comment: Characters don't need to be escaped within a regex character class; that is, within the square brackets. That is, except for the special characters ] \ ^ -. Even then, escaping can usually be avoided by positioning them suitably within the character class. (Other characters can be escaped with a backslash '\' but this is not necessary in a character class.)

Comment: Thanks guys, Really appreciated. Sorry for the late response. Hi Andy if I want to compare two columns straightway, how would I do that

Comment: I did this way `... WHERE GetAlpha(A.ACol4) = GetAlpha(B.BCol4); ` Both `Col4 ` are text. But it gives a `Data Type mismatch error`. I have input sample data as `,,sddll `  and `..sddll ` for both Columns

Comment: It is likely that some of your values are NULLs, whereas GetAlpha() expects a String. I have added to my answer to handle null-values.

Comment: @Andy, Have small clarification if you don't mind. I have used following query `SELECT ACol3, ACol4 FROM Table_A WHERE RegexMatch(ACol4, "screw.*?d+\s*mm"); `. I used following data in ACol4 column. `Pan Head Screw length 18 mm, SCREW18mm, hello `. But it doesn't anything true. Just want to find out whats wrong.

Comment: I added `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5. ` under reference as well.