# MS Access Remove Words from Text

Tags: vba

I'm trying to remove various words from a text field in MS Access. The data might look like:

Hi there @foo, what's new @bar
@goodfriend and I just watched Star Wars
@this and @that and @theother

I want to remove all the words that start with '@'.

Replace() won't work since the words are different in each record.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actualy upvoted CheeseInPosition's answer but just thought I would provide another way if you can't/don't want to do it with regex.  Just wrote a quick function to parse out the words:

```
Public Function RemoveAtWords(strOriginal As String) As String

    Dim strParts() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strParts() = Split(strOriginal, " ")

    For i = LBound(strParts) To UBound(strParts)
        If Left(strParts(i), 1) <> "@" Then
            RemoveAtWords = RemoveAtWords & " " & strParts(i)
        End If
    Next

    RemoveAtWords = Trim(RemoveAtWords)

End Function
```

You can call that from a query and pass through your string.  Not as efficient because you have to loop through the whole string, but just another option.

Comment: I like both answers, but since VBlades gives a more complete answer, I marked that one as the correct answer. It's not that I have anything against Regex, but I don't use it that much and would have to figure out the correct Regex statement to make that suggestion work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VBA, you should be able to replace text based on regular expressions. See the answer to [replace a column using regex in ms access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188796/replace-a-column-using-regex-in-ms-access-2010) as an example.